# Density of States

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-space, volume, density-of-states

For getting the **density of states** formula for photons, we simply multiply the density of states for atoms by **2** (due to *two spins* of photons).
I am getting the 2D density of states formula as :-
**g(p)dp = 2πApdp/h^2**

I think this is the formula for normal particles, and so for photons I need to multiply it with 2.
But various articles on the internet say that it will be **4**πApdp/h^2 instead of **2**πApdp/h^2 for normal atoms.

Which formula is correct for normal atoms?

Comment: Just a guess, but the reason the sites you're looking at might have multiplied by 2 is that they might be considering (spin 1/2) electrons, which also have two internal states.

Comment: If this is so, which formula should I consider for monoatomic atoms?

Comment: Okay, I got to know that the 2D density of states for a monoatomic gas is given by:
g(ϵ)dϵ = (2πmA)/h^2 dϵ